# My gnome terminal syntax highlight has gone 17.10

Tags: command-line, gnome

When I opened my home directory the other day, I found a lot of files/folders which I did not remember creating. And mistakenly deleted them. After that a lot of things disappeared in some of my software like Atom (all the installed packages got deleted) & git SSH keys also got deleted.

Also, syntax highlight of my terminal also disappeared. I get only white text whether it is any command or the current folder in which I am. I tried to change the settings but all text color changes. I want the default settings.

My terminal when I use system settings:

[image: 1]

When I use custom settings all the text in the terminal changes to that particular color. Please help!!

Edit - Output of command `ls -la` as requested in the comments -

```
hemakshi@hemakshis:~$ ls -la
total 104
drwxr-xr-x 23 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 18  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root     4096 May 18  2017 ..
drwxrwxr-x  9 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 13 13:38 .atom
-rw-------  1 hemakshi hemakshi 1264 Jan 15 21:41 .bash_history
drwxr-xr-x 17 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 17 19:05 .cache
drwxr-xr-x 20 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 17 19:05 .config
drwxrwxr-x  5 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan  5 13:34 Courses
drwx------  3 root     root     4096 Sep 26 11:34 .dbus
drwxr-xr-x  2 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Dec 25 11:42 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  3 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 May 17  2017 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  3 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 13 13:00 Downloads
drwx------  2 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 13 12:59 .gconf
-rw-r--r--  1 hemakshi hemakshi   68 Jan 13 14:09 .gitconfig
drwx------  2 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 13 13:39 .gnupg
-rw-------  1 hemakshi hemakshi  660 Jan 18  2018 .ICEauthority
drwxr-xr-x  3 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 13 12:56 .local
drwx------  5 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 13 13:39 .mozilla
drwxr-xr-x  2 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 May 18  2017 Music
drwxr-xr-x  6 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 13 15:29 .npm
drwxr-xr-x  5 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 17 19:01 Pictures
drwx------  3 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 13 12:57 .pki
drwxrwxr-x  8 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 13 14:14 Projects
drwxr-xr-x  2 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 May 18  2017 Public
drwx------  2 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 Jan 13 14:26 .ssh
-rw-r--r--  1 hemakshi hemakshi    0 Jan 13 14:27 .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwxr-xr-x  2 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 May 18  2017 Templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 hemakshi hemakshi 4096 May 18  2017 Videos
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `ls -la` in your question *as copiable text*, or through [paste.ubuntu.com](https://paste.ubuntu.com)?

Comment: please specifically use `ls -la` to show also the hidden files/directories beginning with a '.' - like `.config` or `.atom` for exampl

Comment: Yes done. Sorry for that previous mistake

Comment: when was 'the other day'? before january 13th 12:56?

Comment: I don't remember exactly. But I guess it was 13th or 12th Jan. Because I created a new SSH key for my github on 13th so probably 12th or 13th Jan.

Comment: All of my chrome extensions also got deleted. (such a stupid mistake -_-) Really regretting doing that. :'(